# Positional notation base 5 to base 10

Tags: notation

I know how to convert numbers written in base 10 to fractions. Now I want to understand how to convert numbers in base 5 to numbers in base 10.

Lets consider for example

$$(0,4\overline{1})_5,$$
how can I convert this in $(fraction)_{10}$?

Comment: think of it as a series, equal to $\frac 45 +\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\frac 1{5^n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base 5 the first digit after the decimal point represents a multiple of $5^{-1}$ or 1/5, the second digit after the decimal point represents a multiple of $5^{-2}$ or 1/25 and so on.

So $0.4_5$ as a fraction is 4/5 and $0.41_5$ as a fraction is 4/5 + 1/25 = 21/25.

The recurring $0.0\overline{1}_5$ is a little more complicated, but if you notice that

$$4 \times 0.0\overline{1}_5 = 0.0\overline{4}_5 = 0.1_5 = \frac{1}{5}$$

then you are almost there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not understand the second equality, i.e. $0.0\overline{4}_5=0.1_5$. Can you explain me please?

Comment: In base 10 we know that $0.\overline{9}=1$ and $0.0\overline{9}=0.1$. In base 5 there are equivalent equalities except that the relevant digit is 5-1=4 instead of 10-1=9.